# Typecasting return value of function to pointer type

Tags: c, embedded

I have following code:

```
#define PLL0STAT        (*((volatile unsigned short*) 0xE01FC088))
// Function Prototypes
void diaplayInRow1WithPosition(unsigned char* data, unsigned char position);
unsigned char convertLowerNibbleToASCIIValue(unsigned char data);
void func1 (void)
{
    unsigned char temp = (unsigned char) PLL0STAT; // Interested in last byte only
    temp = convertLowerNibbleToASCIIValue(temp);
    diaplayInRow1WithPosition(&temp,15);
}
```

instead of above code, I thought I will replace the last line with one step and used below statement

```
diaplayInRow1WithPosition(((unsigned char*)convertLowerNibbleToASCIIValue(temp3)),15);
```

But the code compiles correctly, but nothing is displayed in LCD. Not able to makeout the reason. Typecasting is done correctly for the pointer I thought. Is there any other issue?

Comment: What makes you think converting a character value to a pointer will produce a meaningful result?

Comment: The code is not equivalent. The original is passing the pointer to location containing the computed value. The changed one is passing the value as the pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Is there anyway I can pass the address of this return value to another function without using temporary variable as lvalue? Usage of & like diaplayInRow1WithPosition(&(convertHigherNibbleToASCIIValue(temp3)),14); gives compilation error. I guess the other way is for the function to return reference instead of value and in such case I end up in changing function usage in other places.

Comment: @ShankariAmma The results of any computation in a computer needs to be stored _somewhere_, they cannot be stored in thin air. So either you explicitly create a variable `temp` or if you leave it to the compiler to implicitly create one such variable, as an unnamed one only known by the compiler. The actual machine code will be identical. So the only thing achieved by removing the `temp` variable is that you made the program harder to debug. _Never attempt to micro-optimize code if you don't know how a compiler generates machine code from C code_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original code is already fine. Why you are trying to turn it into an unreadable one-liner, I have no idea. You will not gain performance, you will achieve nothing, you only obfuscate the code. As we can see from the need to ask this question: you have made your code unreadable even to yourself. Just leave the code as it was.

The actual bug comes from the strange cast to `(unsigned char*)` that you have added.